# NSDate Localization

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I have included the following line in my code to try and get the localization of `NSDate` to work.

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:[NSDate date]     
dateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle]);
```

No matter what language I set my simulator to, I keep getting the date in English, e.g. Thursday, November 14, 2013 at 4:36 PM.  I would hope that the date would be displayed in French if I had the simulator set to French.

I've done all the usual, uninstall app, clean build etc.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,
Kev.

Comment: Are you fully restarting your app after changing the language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't change with the language of your app, it changes with the region, it happened to me in the past :)

Go to settings where you change your language, and instead change your Region Format

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the ***Region Format*** on your device (also in the International settings)

Also, you will need to fully relaunch the app for the change to take effect